# Raid 10 - lost of data after replacing one disk with nonformated disk (RAW)

Tags: hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, rebuild

I hope someone will be able to help me out on this one, because I can't google my specific situation. I have a RAID 10 array created with 4 disks. One disk failed - array became critical, so I replaced it with new drive (it is bigger in size, but I didn't realise that). I forgot to format the new disk before I connected it and rebuild an array, so my whole partition (raid array) became raw. What I did was, that I used EaseUs partition master and manually deleted 10MB partition that was before my NTFS partition and extended my NTFS partition to beginning of disk (array). Now my partition is recognisable and I can open it, but I can't see any files. I do see folders, exactly as they were before, but all empty. I believe, that data is somewhere on the disks, because I see that there is exactly same free space as it was before and my raid manager software is showing me, that first disk in array - the one that I replaced is using all that space, but other ones are full completely. Here is the screenshot:
[RaidXpert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlYny.png)

I already tried with EaseUs recovery wizard, but unsuccessful. Is there any way that I can recover my previous state? I am using Windows 10. Motherboard is Gigabyte B450 DS3H and I am using hardware Raid.

PS.: Is it normal that every time I turn my PC off, I hear loud click in one of the disks - like is force stopped somehow when is still spinning? This is especially bothering me when I am using Ubuntu (I have dual boot system), because on Ubuntu I don't have my hardware raid drivers. I thought that this was the cause for first disk to fail, but as it happens, it wasn't that disk, that was making noises.

Answer (score 0):

No clicking drives are not normal, they are BAD drives. This is the drive that must be replaced and may most likely caused the raw data. Recovering raw data will require data recovery software.